# reStructuredText styles

Tags: stylesheet, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I found [this guide](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/static/manual.pdf) for [rst2pdf](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf) to find out how to style a reStructuredText file in the resulting pdf document. Having the following in my JSON stylesheet, for example, it is successfully applied to the *whole* document:

```
"pageSetup" : {
    "size": "A4",
    "width": null,
    "height": null,
    "margin-top": "2cm",
    [...]
    "margin-gutter": "0cm"
}
```

How is a particular style applied only to a specific class? For example, how can I apply a particular font the to the `h1` class? My immediate difficulty stems from the fact that I'm unsure about whether it's actually called `h1`, `H1`, `header1`, or `Header1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`rst2pdf.py` manual](http://ralsina.me/static/manual.pdf) does not seem very informative with regards to the style names. However, the section on Styles (chapter 8) has this example:

```
["heading1" , {
  "parent": "normal",
  "fontName": "Tuffy_Bold",
  "fontSize": 18,
  "keepWithNext": true,
  "spaceAfter": 6
}],
```

So it seems that `heading1` is the appropriate style name.

One thing to note is that

> If your document requires a style that is not defined in your stylesheet, it will print a warning and use bodytext instead.

So presuming that you don't get any warnings when generating your document the styles must be set in the default stylesheet, so have a look through this to get a feel for the style names used.

You can make rst2pdf print the default stylesheet using

```
rst2pdf --print-stylesheet
```

If you want to add styles, just create a stylesheet, (or take the standard stylesheet and modify it) and pass it with the -s option

```
rst2pdf mydoc.txt -s mystyles.txt
```